# Print double with a given precision rounded in given direction

Tags: c++, rounding

Note: I know there are some similar questions but I couldn't find the answer to what I'm asking here.

I want to print a double to a std::ostream rounded towards +oo or -oo with n decimal places.

Multiplying by 10^n, floor'ing or ceil'ing, and then multiplying the result by 10^-n is not an option, since the result might not be representable.

What I have so far is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cfenv>

int main()
{
    double one_third = 1.0/3.0;
    std::cout.precision(4);
    fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
    std::cout << one_third << std::endl;
    fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
    std::cout << one_third << std::endl;
}
```

The output with gcc-4.7.2 is the following:

```
0.3333
0.3333
```

I was expecting:

```
0.3333
0.3334
```

So what is wrong with this code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT: This must be a GCC 4.7.2 bug. The code works fine in GCC 4.8.1, but fails in 4.7.2.**

This code ([example on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/4icSe5)) works just fine with GCC 4.8.1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cfenv>

int main()
{
    double one_third = 1.0/3.0;
    std::cout.precision(4);

    std::fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
    std::cout << one_third << std::endl;

    std::fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
    std::cout << one_third << std::endl;

    return (0);
}
```

Program output:

```
0.3333
0.3334
```

Comment: Ah.. do you know if there are c++ equivalents for manipulating the FPU?

Comment: @mvc It appears so, I just checked in 4.7.2 - it does not produce the correct result as 4.8.1 on `ideone.com`.

Comment: Problem is gone after upgrading the compiler. Thanks!